# Problems with Ctrl+Backspace in Sublime Text 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

I regularly use ctrl+backspace in Sublime 3 to delete a whole word, but recently it stopped working. Nothing happens when I try to use it.

I have tried mapping it in Key Bindings - User as

> { "keys": ["ctrl+backspace"], "command": "delete_word", "args": { "forward": false } }

but still no luck. Have also checked that it is not caught by AutoHotKey or other programs running in the background. 
Anyone else having the same issue with Sublime 3? Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FindKeyConflicts) plugin, available via Package Control. Once installed, open the Command Palette and type ***`findkeycon`*** until the `FindKeyConflicts` options appear. Choose `All Conflicts` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once the new tab opens and is populated, search in it for `ctrl+backspace` and see if anything comes up. Once you find the offending plugin, you can use [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to edit the appropriate `.sublime-keymap` file and change that key combo to something else.

Good luck!

Comment: The PackageResourceEditor link is broken. It appears to now be called PackageResourceViewer (https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer). I followed your directions and it worked.

Comment: @CurtisYallop thanks for the heads up, I changed the link and the name of the package.